# To check string in jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

for password validation i am using `equalTo:"#password"` Whether it is possible to check some sting by giving as `equalTo:"string to check"` in jquery.validate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`equalTo`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/equalTo#other) only takes a selector here, but you can make [a custom method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) for the check you want:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("equals", function(value, element, param) { 
  return this.optional(element) || value === param; 
}, jQuery.format("You must enter {0}"));
```

Then you can use the a rule with the same name:

```
equals:"string to check"
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EEF6w/).

Comment: i need to use notequalto but no option for that in jquery.validate

Comment: @Mohan - you could create a similar method, `notequals` and just change the `value === param` to `value != param`.

Answer (score 0):

Override the equalTo: with below function

```
equalTo: function(element) {                    
                        if( ( 
                                $("#password").val() == "Your String Value Here"
                            ) {
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```