# jQuery validation depends

Tags: jquery, validation, depends

Is it possible to add a depends onto an `equalTo` rule?

i.e.,

```
rule {   
    myFormFierld: if textbox name has been filled out add this equalTo rule..
}
```

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/EEF6w/

Comment: duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439119/to-check-string-in-jquery-validate

Answer (score 1):

The answer is ***yes***.
You just need to declare it that way

```
billingAddress: {
  required:true,
  minlength:5
  equalTo: {
    param: "#shippingaddress",
    depends: "#compare:checked"
  }
}
```

Simple and beautiful.
Via [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2456) ticket.