# jquery validate field equalTo element only if another field a certain value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jquery validate plugin I'm using the rule equalTo to validate a field as follows:

```
$('#booking').validate({

ignoreTitle: true, 
rules: {
    payments: {
        equalTo: {
            param: "#sales",
            depends: function(element) { return $("#status").val() == 'invoiced'; }
        }
    },

}
});
```

I can get this to work but now I'd only like this rule to apply only if a select option is a particular value. I'm lost on this and not sure how to make the equalTo rule optional dependant on another field value

I saw depends rule but cant find any documentation on this

Can anyone give me some pointers please?

I;ve created a jsfiddle to help:

http://jsfiddle.net/longestdrive/SneAF/2/

Thanks

Updated: I've tried the depends but not working as expected:

Also found some similar/duplicate questions:
[jQuery Validation - require field only if another field is filled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484323/jquery-validation-require-field-only-if-another-field-is-filled?rq=1)
and
[jQuery validation depends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725584/jquery-validation-depends)

Comment: Since part of the issue was a misspelling, please include the HTML markup so that this question remains useful long after the links go dead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were some errors in your `depends`-rule:

1. You need to use another selector to get the currently selected option:
    `$("#status option:selected")`
2. The value of your dependent option was `Invoiced`, not `invoiced`

This is the final result (As RobM mentioned, you could even specify more exact error messages:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SneAF/10/)**

```
$('#booking').validate({
    ignoreTitle: true, 
    rules: {
        payments: {
            equalTo: {
                param: '#sales',
                depends: function(element) { 
                    return $("#status option:selected").val() == 'invoiced'; 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        payments: {
            equalTo: "Payments must equal Sales when Status is 'Invoiced'."
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Great - thank you. Got it working in fiddle but not in form so i'll work on that or another question :) Thanks

Comment: I was about to answer this, but Nirazul beat me to it. :) You can also customize the message to be more informative, as you can see in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SneAF/14/