# JQuery: Form Validation plugin - validate specific string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form that uses this plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Works great - but I cant figure how to validate by a specific string in-putted into a text field. For example, I want to create a rule that only validates a field if the users input is "foo".

There is documentation here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#API_Documentation

But none of them seem to be the one I want. Does anyone know a way to get round this?

Thanks!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439119/to-check-string-in-jquery-validate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple one...

```
$.validator.addMethod("equals", function(value, element, string) {
    return value === string;
}, $.validator.format("Please enter '{0}'"));
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {            
        name: {
            required: true,
            equals: "foo"
        }
    }
});
```

Updated according to your requirement

```
$.validator.addMethod("equals", function(value, element, string) {
    return $.inArray(value, string) !== -1;
}, $.validator.format("Please enter '{0}'"));
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {            
        name: {
            required: true,
            equals: ["foo", "bar", 'blah"]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: "Please enter either '{0}' or '{1}' or '{2}'"
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks - I think that is what I need. Dont suppose you know a way to modify it to say equals: "foo" or "bar" or "blah" (ie have multiple correct inputs)

Comment: You mean u want multiple string validations done?? like the input can be equal to either "foo" or "bar" or "blah"...

Answer (score 1):

referred from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
);
```

now validate textbox:

```
$("#Textbox").rules("add", { regex: "/* your regex */" })
```

Comment: Thanks, -but I am not sure how to set this up along side my current script. Would it be something like this http://jsfiddle.net/MeltingDog/CVHKj/

Comment: more easier, $.validator.addMethod('Foo', function (value) { 
    return /^Regex/.test(value); 
}, 'Not valid Foo'); then add this Foo class to your text box