# How i can verify an input for specific text on jQuery Validator?

Tags: jquery, validation, equals, verify

I am trying make a simple verify input with jQuery Validator. But i couldn't find how to verify input's value to custom text. For example;

verify input:

```
<input type="text" name="verify" id="verify" required class="contact-input">
```

Javascript:

```
var rnuma = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var rnumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
var sum = rnuma + rnumb;

$("#contact-form").validate({
    rules: {
         verify: { 
              value: sum
         },
    },
});
```

How can I check the equality? I have previously added equalTo to the page with another input, but I am looking for a better way.

Comment: Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209300/jquery-form-validation-plugin-validate-specific-string)

Comment: How i will connect it to variable?