# jQuery Validation plugin rule to check textbox value is equal to some text

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a text box and I want to check whether the user entered value is equal to "Jhon" or some name. I tried with EqualTo validation rule but it doesnt work.

```
$('#home').validate({
        rules: {            
          name: {
            required: true,
            equalTo: 'Jhon'
          },

           highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
          },
          success: function(element) {
            element
            .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
            .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
            }
      });

});
```

Comment: From the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method/): *equalTo( other ) - Type: Selector -
The selector for the element to compare the current values* - so you need to pass a selector to compare values, not a string

Comment: possible duplicate of [To check string in jquery.validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439119/to-check-string-in-jquery-validate)

Comment: Whenever posting JavaScript, you should also post the corresponding HTML markup.

Answer (score 5):

Three problems with your code:

1)  The `equalTo` rule is for matching one field to another field, not a string.  To match a string, you'll need to write a custom method using [the `addMethod` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod), which I'll show below.

2)  You've incorrectly placed `highlight` and `success` *inside* of the `rules` option.  Only field names and rule declarations go inside of `rules`.  The `highlight` and `success` callback functions are *siblings* of `rules`, not descendants.  You also incorrectly placed a `);` inside of `.validate()`.

3)  You're using the `highlight` callback function but you're not using its complementary function, `unhighlight`.  Whatever you set with `highlight`, should only be removed using `unhighlight`.

---

This is your corrected code below...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("customrule", function(value, element, param) { 
        return this.optional(element) || value === param; 
    }, "You must enter {0}");

    $('#home').validate({
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                customrule: 'John'
            }
        },
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
        },
        success: function (element) {
            element.text('OK!').addClass('valid');
        }
    });

});
```

**Working DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/VYceT/